# Why Xcode refuses to show the TableViewCell class for the prototype cell on storyboard?

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard

I have a TableViewObject on my storyboard which has a corresponding UITableView class.
Within that TableViewObject I also have the 'cell' which manages the layout of a given prototype cell - the class associated with this is of type UITableViewCell.

The issue is that no matter where on the storyboard I click, when I show assistant editor it opens the UITableView class - not the one corresponding to the UITableViewCell.

I think it hasn't always been this way because I managed to drag/drop controls to make outlets in the past but now it refuses to comply - what can I try to fix this?

I've confirmed that the UITableViewCell class is the one shown in the Identity Inspector for the cell and also tried deleting the Derived Data folder that someone recommended - but this hasn't solved it.

To give some further detail, for other TableViewController/Cell combos I have the option by clicking 'automatic' of selecting one of two files, but for the problematic one there is only one file (see screenshots).[![enter image description here][2]][2]

[image]

Comment: By the way, a few times you said the “UITableView class”, but the screen snapshot is the view controller class, not the table view class. Out of curiosity, which is it?

Comment: For me at least, I used to always have this “problem” when I tapped on the cell and expected the cell's source to be an option for the assistant editor, but it won't be. I eventually trained myself to remember to tap on something _inside_ the cell prototype (e.g. select the control for which I want to add the outlet/action), and then the cell’s base class becomes an option in the assistant editor. It always struck me as odd that clicking on the cell, itself, was insufficient, but I have now acclimatized myself to this behavior. Until I trained myself, that was usually the problem.

Comment: If not, it could be base class for the cell has not been set correctly, the class not of correct type, or just one of Xcode weird behaviors where one has to quit Xcode, empty derived data, restart Xcode and rebuild. But we will need more data than this to reproduce the problem, because it does work. It's just finicky.

Comment: e.g. https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9kjg.gif

Answer (score -2):

Don't use assistant editors at all. They are a dead letter. If you want to display the code for the table view cell subclass at the same time as the storyboard, just Option-click on the code file for the table view cell subclass in the project navigator — or select the prototype cell, switch to the Identity inspector on the right, and Option-click the little arrow next to the class name.